# How to understand float('nan')? What is the use of float?

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning about missing values in Python and came across an article that mentioned NaN.

This is the data with five columns and six rows. I don't know how to attach the data file here. Sorry.
five columns: name, age, state, point, and other

```
     name   age state  point  other
    Alice  24.0    NY    NaN    NaN
      NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
  Charlie   NaN    CA    NaN    NaN
     Dave  68.0    TX   70.0    NaN
    Ellen   NaN    CA   88.0    NaN
    Frank  30.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Here are the two lines of code in the article.

```
print(df == float('nan'))
print(df = float('nan'))
```

It says that NaN always returns False for ==, and True for !=.
What is this code about? How to understand "float"?
Could you please explain this to me?

Thank you very much.

Best,

Sagum

Answer (score 1):

[NaN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (Not A Number) is classically a way to identify missing values. It is a `float` type object and can be defined using `first('nan')` the fake way that `1.23` can be defined using `float('1.23')`. You can also define infinite with `float('inf')`.

Some modules directly define a NaN object, which is the case of [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
from numpy import nan
```

If you are working with integers, strings, etc.  in pandas, you can also use the type-aware NA with `pandas.NA`/`pd.NA`.

Further references:

- [pandas: working with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)
- [pandas: nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Regarding your question, it is difficult to answer without reading the article, but what you described is incorrect.

`print(df == float('nan'))` will always return `False` as `float('nan')==float('nan')` is `False`.

`print(df = float('nan'))` will raise a SyntaxError.

The correct way to check for NaN values is [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)

```
df.isna()
```

Which returns one `True` or `False` per cell.

To get an aggregated value, you need to combine for example with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
# is there at least one NaN in the whole DataFrame?
df.isna().any().any()
```

Comment: Hi, mozway. Thank you for your reply. But print(df = float('nan')) doesn't raise a syntax error. It gives results. Below are results for the first three rows.
#    name   age  state  point  other
# 0  True  True   True   True   True
# 1  True  True   True   True   True
# 2  True  True   True   True   True

Comment: @sagum sorry it should be a TypeError `print(df = float('nan'))` -> `TypeError: 'df' is an invalid keyword argument for print()`. But for sure, this cannot give you this result (double check the exact syntax you used)

Comment: Hi, mozway. I double checked the syntax and it works. In this example, df is the name of the dataframe.  I should have told you earlier. Sorry. BTW, I want to post that part of the article, but not sure how to do it? Can I take a snapshot and post it here? Thank you.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say `print(df=...)` should be treated as parameter of `print`. I don't understand… of course you can post a snapshot, maybe also your full code

Comment: Hi, mozway. I don't know how to post the snapshot. Can you please check this link for the article? Thank you.   https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-nan-judge-count/

Comment: @sagum the article uses `!=` (different) not `=` (assignment) and this gives all `True`: `print(df != float('nan'))`. But I realize that the issue is that the `!` got removed by the markdown in your post!

Answer (score 0):

A `float` is a 64-bit* [IEEE-754 Floating-Point Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Most values that can be represented by floats, we can write as literals (e.g. `1.5` or `52.0`). However, the values for Infinity (`inf`) and "Not-a-Number" (`NaN`), which the IEEE-754 standard requires, can only be reliably assigned by converting those strings into floats. That's what `float('nan')` does - it creates a float whose value is `NaN`.

The article you read is misleading. According to the IEEE-754 standard, the value `NaN` works differently from any other float value - it will *always* return false when used in any comparison with another number, unless that comparison is `!=`, in which case it will *always* return true. This is even the case when comparing it to itself:

```
>>> var = float('nan')
>>> var != var
True
```

as such, using `NaN` in comparisons is not very useful.

Instead, to check if a variable contains the value `NaN`, do

```
import math
...
if math.isnan(some_variable):
    ...
```

or just

```
if some_variable == some_variable:
    ...
```

since that will always be true if `some_variable` is not `NaN`, and will always be false if it is `NaN`.

The article is probably guiding you to check whether the values in a column of the dataframe are `NaN` and use different behavior accordingly.

---

*in python, at least - in most languages `float` is 32 bits and `double` is the 64-bit equivalent

Comment: Hi Green Cloak Guy, thank you for your reply. You are right that the article is guiding me to check for NaNs in columns.